# Magento admin: Making simple admin import interface with start-button

Tags: magento-1.6, magento

I am trying to make a Magento module, to enable our Magento-webshop customers to import all our products automatically. Since I'm not yet very proficient in Magento development, I run into a few stops on the way... :-)

Right now I try to make a AdminController in which the index page should simply display a text and **a button to start the import process**. It's the "addButton" part, that I have trouble with:

```
public function indexAction() {
  $this->loadLayout();

  $block = $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
    ->setText("
      <h1>Import/update products</h1>
      <p>On this page you can start the import of all products from Misstoro.</p>
      ...bla bla bla...
    ");
  $this->_addContent($block);

  $url = $this->getUrl('*/*/do_import');

  $this->_addButton('button_import', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('import')->__('Start import'),
    'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $url .'\')',
    'class'     => 'add',
  ));

  $this->renderLayout();
}
```

**$this->_addButton** gives me an "Call to undefined method" error.

What is the right way to do this?

/ Carsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with a little more research:

```
$url = $this->getUrl('*/*/do_import');

$block = $this->getLayout()
  ->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
  ->setData(array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('import')->__('Start import'),
    'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $url .'\')',
    'class'     => 'add',
  ));
$this->_addContent($block);
```